# Происхождение мата

Tags: этимология, обсценная-лексика

Как возникли матерные слова? Есть ли какая-то связь с тюркскими языками, или, наоборот, такая лексика имеет славянские корни?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это сложный вопрос, и "формат" не позволяет здесь все подробно обсуждать.
Если говорить об этимологии, то все (или почти все) т.н. матерные слова имеют древние славянские корни, гипотеза о тюркском (или даже монгольском) происхождении не имеет под собой ничего исторического.

А вот вопрос о том, когда и почему вдруг появилось само понятие, табуированность некоторых слов, это интереснее. 
Достаточно сказать, что среди лингвистов нет единого мнения, что относить к конкретно к мату, а что просто к нецензурной лексике.
"Состав" табуированной лексики и конкретные "термины" непостоянны, что-то добавляется, что-то уходит.

Вообще табуированных по разным причинам слов в русском (древнерусском) всегда было великое множество, но нынешний мат не сразу стали относить к этому ряду. Слова эти сами по себе табуированными не были, просто постепенно они стали употребляться исключительно в "ночи любви" (на Купалу, например). 
С исчезновением подобных традиций и под влиянием христианства "матерные" слова заняли современную нишу. Окончательно запрет на употребление оных следует видимо отнести к эпохе "рафинированных" манер при дворах российских Императриц, начиная если не с Екатерины I, то с Анны.

Я не даю ссылок, в интернете полно исследований и псевдоиссдедований на эту тему, тут даже и не знаешь, чему верить.

Answer (score -1):

Мат=материализация. Проговаривание нехваток на телесном уровне ("у кого что болит").

Явление это антикультурное, поскольку культура зиждется на сублимации либидо.
Мат существовал до зарождения культуры, после её возникновения был табуирован, но не смирился.
С тех пор ведёт с нею борьбу не на жизнь, а на смерть.)))))

Comment: Что из себя представляет "сублимация либидо" у дельфинов?

Comment: Дельфины не сублимируют, и потому у них нет культуры.