# Сколько матерных корней в русском языке

Tags: обсценная-лексика

Всем известны 3 матерных корня:

> -хуй-, -пизд- и -ебл-.

А существуют ли другие? В частности, относится ли к ним корень "-муд-", который можно встретить в таких словах:

> муди, мудозвон, мудила и т. п.

Comment: Вопрос бессодержательный, говорилось уже, что само понятие мата, матерности - вопрос более этикетный, чем лингвистический. Мат и обценная лексика - разные понятия.  Пока мы не договоримся, что считать матом, разговора не будет. Смотрите, например, здесь. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31733

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как возник мат?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31733/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82)

Answer (score 1):

Других столь же продуктивных корней не существует, а приведенные вами часто называют "тремя китами русского мата" или "обсценной триадой". Правда, не понятно, почему у вас выделен корень *ебл*, когда должно быть *еб*:

> ср. **еб**ать, **еб**лан.

Из словаря:

> ОБСЦЕ́ННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. [от лат. obscēnus - отвратительный, непристойный] *Лингв.* Оскорбительный, бранный.

Корень *муд*, встречающийся в таких матерных словах, как *мудак*, *мудить*, нельзя назвать обсценным: это будет не совсем корректно — а вот слова, которые от него образуются, можно.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему корень "еб" — обсценный, а корень "муд" — нет? Каковы критерии?

Comment: @NickVolynkin речь немного о другом: корень сам по себе нельзя (ну или нежелательно) считать обсценным, а вот слово, в котором присутствует этот корень, можно. На мой взгляд, называть *морфему* какой-либо (обсценной, желательной, хвалебной и т. д., и т. п.) странно.

Comment: Тогда я вижу противоречие, в том что три основных корня называют обсценной триадой. Получается, что понятие «матерный корень» не имеет смысла?

Comment: @NickVolynkin смысл-то оно имеет: мы же с вами понимаем, что имеется в виду. Обсценная триада = три **слова**, от которых образуется самое большое количество производных. Тут чисто терминологический вопрос, в котором я могу ошибаться; можно предположить, что *матерный корень* — тот, который участвует в образовании матерных слов, но подобных употреблений я не встречал.

Comment: Тогда предлагаю уточнить, что вообще любой корень некорректно называть матерным. Или вопрос об этом задать. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin давайте я вам предложу задать такой терминологический вопрос, а то вы давно ничего не спрашивали) Может, кто выскажется, и я поправлю